# dynamic 1-2-3 column layout

Tags: html, css, layout

i'm looking for solution how to create dynamic 3 column layout, but if the left column is emtpy, the content and right columns will be widder. Like it's in joomla templates, if you don't put any module to the left position, it will expand.

Answer (score 1):

Try using css to select siblings of the empty element using the el:empty (empty element) and el ~ el (general siblings) selectors.

For example, this code sets a 3 column layout, then selects siblings of the empty left column and adjusts their widths.

If you have classes on each column that'd make it even easier, but this is the basic idea:

```
.wrapper {
    zoom: 1;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.column {
    width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.66% 
}
.column:empty {
    width: 0%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.column:empty ~ .column {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 0.98%;
}
```

for the markup of

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column"><!--This needs to be completely empty for the solution to work --></div>
    <div class="column">
       Content
    </div>
    <div class="column">
       Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Just be aware that if your empty element has a space character, it won't register as empty. eg:

```
<div class="column">
</div>
```

Comment: That's a clever idea, but i discovered that joomla have it's own php function to count modules in module positions and according to that it can render page without column and add different css, but this idea is goodfor non-joomla projects, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either separate page templates that will be displayed based on the page content, or you could do it after the page load with javascript, but I would not recommend that.
I'm sure Joomla will show a different template if a column is empty.

Another option to have 'dynamic' column widths is using a table, but you don't want to go there :-)

Comment: javascript is simple solution, but if user turn js off it breaks design, maybe is there something simillar with php.

Comment: Javascript is a solution though, that will only be executed after the HTML has been parsed and the columns are visible. This will mean a 'jump' on page load. You should try and avoid using javascript for altering lay-out, which can be done before the page loads. The only good solution here is to have seperate templates, or at least classes based on the content.